# Использование более одного уникального ключа в таблице

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Хочу узнать, если мой сервер всегда взаимодействует с БД через уникальные хеши(`OPJcgTSL...`) Есть ли смысл добавлять еще одно дополнительное поле в БД

```
id (int) PRIMARY_KEY c AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Или хватит только одного поля с уникальными хешами, без `id (int)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От задачи зависит. Если у вас одно поле, то второе не нужно, а если десяток, то уникальность определяется не полем, а бизнес логикой приложения, которое в эту таблицу пишет.

`id:1, name:иванов` и `id:2, name:иванов` - это у вас разные или одинаковые записи?

Рассуждать надо с ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: Я хочу хранить книги. 
hash | title | authorId | topics ...
Вот я думаю, что все таки можно довольствоваться только уникальными hash и не создавать еще id

Comment: @Zow я бы добавил id для связей с другими таблицами. плюс добавил бы ISBN книги. ну и хэш, но не короткий, а длинный и чтоб не сильно отличался, если содержимое книг похоже, т.е. без лавинного эффекта https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лавинный_эффект - так можно будет найти дубли в слегка отличающихся книгах